# CSS : page-break-inside: avoid doesn't work in table row

Tags: html, css, html-table, page-break, page-break-inside

I'm using a PHP script to generate a table to display a measurement result.
It's working well but when printing I have some trouble with page break inside Table row.

The border of the `<tr>` with the rowspan continues on the footer / header of the page and the page break doesn't work.

I have tried several methods but nothing has changed : `page-break-inside : avoid` doesn't work in this table.

Have you got an idea? or do you see any mistakes?

Thanks for your help ! :)

Edit : 
In fact, After many other tests, page-break-inside : avoid will work if you set  display : block.
But display:block will break the table layout :/
How it's possible to do this ?
Thanks

Code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
 <!-- Style CSS A garder -->
 <STYLE>
  html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
   font-family: "Times New Roman", "Arial", serif;
   margin : 0px;
  }
  table,thead,tbody, tfoot{
   border-collapse: collapse;
   padding:0 !important;
   margin:0 !important;
   width : 100%;
  } 
  TD {
   padding : 2px;
  }
  .TrTdEntete{
   padding:0 !important;
   margin:0 !important;
  }
  .TableGenerale{
   width : 100%;
  }
  .TableSecondeEntete{
   width : 100%;
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .TableContenu{
            margin-top : 5px;
   /*width : 1024px;*/  
   border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .TableGenerale td{
   height : 30px;
            margin-top : 0px;  
  }
  .TableContenu td,th {
   height : 30px;
            margin-top : 0px;
   border: 1px solid black;   
  } 

  /* page break ne fonctionne pas !!!*/
  tr.page-break-avoid {
   page-break-inside: avoid !important;
   page-break-before: always !important;
  }

  td.page-break-avoid {
   page-break-inside: avoid !important;
   page-break-before: always !important;
  }  
  .imgbanc {
   width : 100%;
   max-width : 100%; 
   height : 500px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin-top: 10px
  }
  .NOK{
   color : RED;
  }

  #contenu{
   padding : 5px;
  }

     @media print {
   tr, td{
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid !important; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    page-break-inside: avoid !important; /* Firefox */
    break-inside: avoid !important; /* IE 10+ */
   }
  }
 
        </STYLE>
</HEAD> 
<BODY>
<TABLE class="TableGenerale"><THEAD>
                         <!-- Premiere Entête qui sera afficher à chaque debut de page  --><TR><TD class="">[task-XXXX]</TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="3" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><!-- Fin premiére entête  --></THEAD><TBODY><!-- Partie affichée une seule fois  --><TR><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR><TD class="">Bench software version : $version</TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><!-- Fin Partie affichée une seule fois   -->
              <TR  class="TrTdEntete">
               <TD  class="TrTdEntete"colspan="6">
                <TABLE  class="TableSecondeEntete">
                 <THEAD>
                  <!-- Seconde Entête qui sera afficher à chaque debut de page  --><TR><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="6" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</TD></TR><TR><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</TD><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="3" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</BR>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</TD><TD class="">STAMP</TD></TR><!-- Fin Seconde entête  -->
                 </THEAD> 
                 <TBODY>
                  <TR class="TrTdEntete">
                   <TD class="TrTdEntete" colspan="6" id="contenu">
                    <TABLE class="TableContenu">
                     <THEAD>
                      <!-- Troisiéme entête qui sera présente uniquement dans le tableau du contenu pvri --><TR><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</TD><TD class="">MEASUREMENT</TD><TD class="">NOMINAL VALUE TOLERANCE</TD><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >MEASURED VALUES</TD><TD class="">COMMENTS</TD></TR><!-- fin Troisiéme entête  -->
                     </THEAD> 
                     <tbody>
                      <!-- Corps du PVRI --><TR><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="2" colspan="1" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="6" colspan="1" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" ></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" ></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="5" colspan="1" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" ></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="1" colspan="2" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class=" page-break-avoid" rowspan="15" colspan="1" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR class="page-break-avoid" ><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><TR><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD></TR><!-- Fin du corps du PVRI  -->
                     </tbody>
                    </table><!-- Fin de la zone PVRI -->
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                 </tbody>
                </table>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
             <tfoot>
              <!-- Footer --><TR><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class="">Lorem ipsum</TD></TR><TR><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class=""></TD><TD class="">June 15/18</TD></TR><!-- Fin Footer -->
                </tfoot></table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Do Chrome and Firefox behave the same here?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome claims to support `break-inside: avoid` on `tr` but not `td` (see https://crbug.com/547972). Have you tried `break-inside: avoid-page;` instead of `page-break-inside: avoid`? They are supposed to be aliased, but maybe Chrome has a bug here.

Comment: Same problem with  break-inside: avoid-page;